# Custom plugin AJAX request results in error HTTP 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Basically I am getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

I am developing a custom plugin which is a csv file upload script.

I used the following script as a demo plugin that was working as expected. With the final version of the plugin I am getting this error, but I can't figure out why it's happening. Any help?

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

class BulkEmail
{    
    private $adminemail;
    function __construct()
    {   
        //new BulkemailImport();
        $this->adminemail = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
        $this->bulk_email_send();
        add_action('wp_ajax_email_csv_import', [$this,'email_csv_import']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_email_csv_import', [$this, 'email_csv_import']); 
 
    }

    public function email_csv_import() {
        global $wpdb;

    
        $fileMimes = array(
            'text/x-comma-separated-values',
            'text/comma-separated-values',
            'application/octet-stream',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'application/x-csv',
            'text/x-csv',
            'text/csv',
            'application/csv',
            'application/excel',
            'application/vnd.msexcel',
            'text/plain'
        );
    
        // Validate selected file is a CSV file or not
        if (!empty($_FILES['csvfile']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['csvfile']['type'], $fileMimes)) {
            // Open uploaded CSV file with read-only mode
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    
            // Skip the first line
            fgetcsv($csvFile);
    
            // Parse data from CSV file line by line        
            while (($getData = fgetcsv($csvFile, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                // Get row data
                $email = $getData[0];
    
                // If user already exists in the database with the same email
                $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}orgsmtp_blukemail WHERE email = %s", $email);
                $check = $wpdb->get_results($query);
                

                if ($check) {
                    $wpdb->update(
                        "{$wpdb->prefix}orgsmtp_blukemail",
                        array('email' => $email),
                        array('email' => $email)
                    );
                } else {
                    $wpdb->insert(
                        "{$wpdb->prefix}orgsmtp_blukemail",
                        array('email' => $email)
                    );
                }
            }
    
            // Close opened CSV file
            fclose($csvFile);
    
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Please select a valid file";
        }
      }

     public function orange_smtp_enqueue_assets() 
     {       
    
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('orange-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), time(), true);

        wp_localize_script('orange-js', 'ajax_object', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            //'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my_csv_upload_nonce'),
        )); 
        wp_enqueue_script('datatables-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/datatables.min.js', array('jquery'), time(), true);
        }
     }
```

**jquery Ajax script**

```
let ajax_url = ajax_object.ajax_url;

jQuery(document).ready(($) =\> {
   jQuery('#uploadcsv').on("click", (e) =\> {
        e.preventDefault();
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('csvfile');
        const file = fileInput.files\[0\];

        if (file) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('action', 'email_csv_import');
            formData.append('nonce', ajax_object.nonce);
            formData.append('csvfile', file);
    
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                const contents = e.target.result;
                // Split CSV content by lines
                const lines = contents.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    
                // Validate each email address
                const validEmails = [];
                const invalidEmails = [];
    
                // Email validity check
                for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    const email = lines[i].trim();
                    if (isValidEmail(email)) {
                        validEmails.push(email);
                    } else {
                        invalidEmails.push(email);
                    }
                }
    
                if (invalidEmails.length > 0) {
                    alert('Invalid email addresses found: ' + invalidEmails.join(', '));
                }
    
                // Only proceed if there are valid email addresses
                if (validEmails.length > 0) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl, // Use ajaxurl global variable in WordPress
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: (data) => {
                            console.log('submit');
                            // Handle success
                        },
                        error: (xhr, status, error) => {
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('No valid email addresses found');
                }
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            console.log('No file selected');
        }
    });
    
    
    // Function to validate email address
        function isValidEmail(email) {
            //return email !== '';
            var email = email.replace(/\s/g, '');
                var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                if (!filter.test(email)) {
                    return false
                }
                return  true
         }
    });
```